# Nav bar logo wont show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

Something strange is happening. I have added my logo to the top right of my website and it shows up perfectly when I look at my website in my localhost on my live server. However, when I look on my publicly hosted website (using GitHub pages) the logo does not show up. Any suggestions on how to fix this or what the issue might be?

**CSS Code**

```
            .bd-grid{
                max-width: 1024px;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 100%;
                grid-column-gap: 2rem;
                width: calc(100% - 2rem);
                margin-left: var(--mb-2);
                margin-right: var(--mb-2);
            }
            .l-header{
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: var(--z-fixed);
                background-color: var(--first-color);
            }

            /*===== NAV =====*/
            .nav{
                height: var(--header-height);
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
                .nav__menu{
                    position: fixed;
                    top: var(--header-height);
                    right: -100%;
                    width: 50%;
                    height: 100%;
                    padding: 2rem;
                    background-color: rgba(219, 236, 244, 0.852);
                    transition: .5s;
                    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
                    font-size: 25px;
                    text-align: left;
                    box-shadow: -2px 0px 4px 1px var(--first-color);
                }
            }
            .nav__item{
                margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
                padding: var(--mb-2);
            }

            .nav__link{
                position: relative;
                color: var(--dark-color);
            }
            .nav__link:hover{
                color: var(--first-color);
                font-weight: 900;
            }
            .nav__logo{
                color: var(--white-color);
                font-family: Snell Roundhand, cursive;
            }
            .nav__toggle{
                color: var(--white-color);
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .nav__logo{
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: 700;
                letter-spacing: -1px;
                display: inline-flex;
                align-items: center;
                column-gap: .5rem;
                transition: .3s;
            }
            
            .logo-image{
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            
            
            .nav__logo-icon{
                font-size: 10px;
                color: var(--first-color);
            }
```

**HTML Code**

```
            <a class="nav__logo" href="/">
                <div class="logo-image">
                      <img src="/assets/img/logosignature.png" class="nav__logo-icon">
                </div>
            </a>

            <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                <ul class="nav__list">
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#home" class="nav__link active">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#skills" class="nav__link">Skills</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#portfolio" class="nav__link">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#contact" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
                <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

[image: When I go to the publicly hosted website and inspect it, it seems as though the image is there but not visible]

[image: This is the style.css section that shows up when I highlight over the logo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple cases why this is happening:

1. File names and extensions are case sensitive on GitHub pages so check if you have entered it correctly in src attribute of image.
2. Try removing the initial '/' character in `src` attribute of image.
3. Path specified might be incorrect

Comment: Yea! It ended up being the second issue

Answer (score 1):

It might be because your logo is local, meaning that it is only on your computer. If you upload it to the internet and then reference the source that way through an image URL, then it should work.

Comment: I checked GitHub which is where I'm hosting my website and the logo image is there. I also have other images throughout the website using the same method and they all show up and have no issues.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to load that image onto Github? Or is it automatic? I'm not too sure how their service works.

Comment: You should also check if you made a case-sensitive error when setting the source of your file. Also, try removing the / at the beginning of your image source.

Comment: You were right! It seems to be the / in the beginning. Just removed it and it worked perfectly. Seems like such a silly mistake now lol. Thank you for the suggestions and help!

Answer (score 1):

don't worry this happened to me on the early days of coding don't worry. First of all I will recommend you to learn the file paths in HTML. Here's a link where you can understand and learn the file paths.

[HTML FILE PATHS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

To answer your question, please upload the whole directory to github pages. What I think is, you have probably missed the  /assets/img/ directory to upload on github. If you can share the github link, I would be more than happy to point out the directory and the missing file.
let me know if this works for you. Happy Coding ;)

Comment: Hey thanks for being so understanding with your advice! I am new and will definitely check that out. Some suggestions from other users helped me get to the source of the issue. You were correct, the issue ended up being that I missed the directory path uploaded to github.

Comment: @lebronjames My Pleasure ;)

Answer (score 0):

Should be a typo. But let me share a cool way to check if the image is around there or not.

You can always open developer tools, go to Sources and locate the uploaded files there.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty cool! I did that and noticed my logo wasn't actually in the uploaded files of the live website even though it was uploaded in my Github folder. After a suggestion from another user, I tried removing the / at the beginning of the src link and it ended up working. Thank you for that trick that's awesome!